# Why checked checkbox isn't recognized on second form submission

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm trying to troubleshoot a bug in my application. I have a form on a page with two fields: a textbox and a checkbox. I'm submitting this form via ajax using :remote => true and displaying the results on the page.

In some cases - even though the checkbox is checked - the console log shows the value as empty.

It looks as though this happens consistently after the first time the form is submitted.

I'm having a hard time tracking down why this could be happening.

Any ideas on where to start investigating would be much appreciated.

Comment: Definitely - what would be the most appropriate portion to show? The view? The controller? I did verify that it is not working properly after the first remote post. When I completely reload the page, it works as expected the first time after the reload.

Comment: What is the view code for `check_box tag` also try to post `parameters` that were getting passed.

Answer (score 0):

I think I sorted this out. On the create.js.erb I was setting the attribute of the checkbox to not checked. I was doing this to reset the form instead of $('#someid > form')[0].reset(); I just changed that out and it seems to be working as expected on each subsequent post.